# how to copy war/jar files from one server to nother server using jenkins

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins server installed on local Vm, I created some jar files using Jenkins pipeline code, now I need to deploy the respective jar files on my GCP Ubuntu VM  Jenkins using pipeline code,
can anyone help me out in solving this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can make use of [Publish over SSH](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh/) plugin to achieve the same.

Comment: Can u provide any tutorial for me pl

Comment: Here some of the blogs to help you with https://nozaki.me/roller/kyle/entry/articles-jenkins-sshdeploy and https://medium.com/@weblab_tech/how-to-publish-artifacts-in-jenkins-f021b17fde71